# Text outside container with Flexbox and React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

With react native and flexbox, I do not understand why the text is outside the container (orange bakcground) ?

```
<View style={styles.main_container}>
    <View style={styles.infos_container}>
        <View style={styles.info_item}>
            <Text style={styles.info_name}>
                Âge
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.info_value}>
                18
            </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.info_item}>
            <Text style={styles.info_name}>
                Médias publics
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.info_value}>
                2
            </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    infos_container: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        padding: 5,
    },
    info_item: {
        margin: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    info_name: {
        color: '#6c757d',
        fontSize: 11,
    },
    info_value: {
        color: '#343a40',
    },
})
```

[image: er]

I just want my blocks `styles.info_item` to be horizontal and orange background

Comment: What is `styles.main_container` value? Please try to change `infos_container.flex` to 0, and see what happen

Comment: if you just want put the text inside the orange container change flex:1 to display:flex
http://uupload.ir/files/r7zy_screenshot_1573720040.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove `flex: 1` from `infos_container` settings `flex: 0` in the `main_container` shouldn't have an effect on the styling of `infos_container`

```
infos_container: {
   backgroundColor: 'orange',
   flexDirection: 'row',
   flexWrap: 'wrap',
   padding: 5,
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You didn't import `main_container` in your style. Maybe you have `flex: 0` inside it
Change your style to this:

```
main_container: {
  flex: 1,
},
infos_container: {
  backgroundColor: 'orange',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  padding: 5,
},
info_item: {
    margin: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
},
info_name: {
    color: '#6c757d',
    fontSize: 11,
},
info_value: {
    color: '#343a40',
},
```